# Getting Unexpected token { at the import statement while running protractor tests from WebStorm

Tags: javascript, protractor, webstorm

I am using Node 6.4.1 and esversion 6.

I am trying to run protractor tests from WebStorm but I am getting the following error during run-time. The browser is getting invoked successfully but then it stops.

```
Error:
    [20:15:29] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
    [20:15:29] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at           http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
    [20:15:33] E/launcher - Error: D:\Protractor-Final\e2e-tests\spec.js:3
    import {WebDriver as browser}  from "selenium-webdriver";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[20:15:33] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

Process finished with exit code 4
```

**Conf.js File**

```
"use strict";
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome'
  }
};
```

**spec.js**

```
"use strict";

import {WebDriver as browser}  from "selenium-webdriver";
import {By as by} from "selenium-webdriver";
import {beforeEach, describe, it} from "selenium-webdriver/testing";
import {element} from "protractor";


describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
let firstNumber = element(by.model('first'));
let secondNumber = element(by.model('second'));
let goButton = element(by.id('gobutton'));
let latestResult = element(by.binding('latest'));

beforeEach(function() {
browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
});

it('should have a title', function() {
  expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
});

it('should add one and two', function() {
  firstNumber.sendKeys(1);
  secondNumber.sendKeys(2);

  goButton.click();

  expect(latestResult.getText()).toEqual('3');
 });

 it('should add four and six', function() {
  firstNumber.sendKeys(4);
  secondNumber.sendKeys(6);

  goButton.click();
  expect(latestResult.getText()).toEqual('10');
  });

 it('should read the value from an input', function() {
   firstNumber.sendKeys(1);
   expect(firstNumber.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('1');
  });
});
```

Comment: Anybody has any solutions for this?

Comment: can you run this without webstorm just using the command line?

Comment: you are using ES6 imports in your code; Node.js has very limited support for ES6 modules (a special flag + .mjs file extension + other conditions should be met to make them work). You have to pre-compile your code with babel and pass the transpiled file to Node.js to avoid syntax errors in runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll admit I'm not familiar with webstorm but I see no reason why you need those imports in your spec file. Protractor should setup these variables when it starts up automatically. It's possible I've missed something but can you try removing them and seeing if your project runs then.

```
import {WebDriver as browser}  from "selenium-webdriver";
import {By as by} from "selenium-webdriver";
import {beforeEach, describe, it} from "selenium-webdriver/testing";
import {element} from "protractor";
```

Comment: @Nickson glad to hear it! Would you mind accepting this answer in cases other people find this question at a later stage?